# How can I use grunt-regarde with grunt-contrib-coffee to only compile changed .coffee files?

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

My project has over 300 CoffeeScript files, so it takes several seconds to recompile everything. I'd like to only recompile the changed CoffeeScript files.

Here's the closest I've come so far, but the "frontend-src/coffeescript" folder structure is being copied from the src directory to the dest directory.

```
coffee: {
  changed: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: './',
    src: ['<%= grunt.regarde.changed %>'],
    dest: 'public/js/',
    ext: '.js'
  }
},
regarde: {
  coffee: {
    files: 'frontend-src/coffeescript/**/*.coffee',
    tasks: ['coffee:changed', 'livereload']
  }
}
```

This is all with Grunt 0.4.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue. I solved it using the `regarde:file` event.

First I listen for changed files by using the `regarde:file` event. This will feed the configuration for two tasks: `clean:coffee` if files in the source location has been deleted and `coffee:refresh` if files have been changed/added.

Then the `regarde` task will trigger its tasks, which will launch `refresh:coffee` (not to be mistaken from `coffee:refresh`). This task will check if there is configuration added for `clean:coffee` and/or for `coffee:refresh` and run these tasks if needed (via function  `grunt.task.run`). If will also reset the flag, which will cause the next received `regarde:file` event to cleanup the configuration again.

**In depth explanation:**

First of all, `regarde` config:

```
 // watch for changed coffeescript files
 coffee: {
    files: 'path/to/coffee/**/*.coffee',
    tasks: ['refresh:coffee', 'livereload']
 },
```

Then I listen for the `regarde:file` event, where I update the `clean:coffee` and `coffee:refresh` file lists in their config.

**Feed the configuration based on the `regarde:file` event:**

```
grunt.event.on('regarde:file', function (status, target, filepath) {
   if (resetFlag) {
      // clean file list from previous cycle, so clean clean:coffee and coffee:refresh
      // file lists
      ...

      resetFlag = false;
   } 
   if (status === 'deleted') {
        if (filepath) {
            // calculate filepath's destination and  
            // add it to clean:coffee filelist
        }
    } else {
        if (!grunt.file.isDir(filepath)) {
            // add filepath to coffee:refresh filelist
        }
    }
}
```

It is easy to update configuration via `grunt.config()` function. Below the code snippets to feed `coffee:refresh` and `clean:coffee`.

**Adding config to `coffee:refresh`:**

```
var config = grunt.config('coffee') || {};
var value = config.refresh || {};
value.files = value.files || [];
...
var cwd = path.dirname(filepath),
    src = path.basename(filepath),
    dest = cwd.replace('path/to/source', 'path/to/dest');
    value.files.push({
       expand:true,
       src:src,
       dest:dest,
       cwd:cwd,
       ext:'.js'
    });
grunt.config('coffee', config);
```

**Adding config to `clean:coffee`:**

```
    var cwd = path.dirname(filepath),
        src = path.basename(filepath),
        dest = cwd.replace('path/to/source', 'path/to/dest');
        value.src.push(path.join(dest, src.replace('coffee', 'js')));
    // clean only what has been removed
        config = grunt.config('clean') || {};

    config.coffee = value;

    grunt.config('clean', config);
```

**Task `refresh:coffee` gets triggered:**

```
    grunt.registerMultiTask('refresh', 'refreshing the changed file(s)', function () {
        this.requires('regarde');

        var tasks = [];
        var clean = grunt.config('clean');

        // check if there is clean:refresh config available
        if (clean && clean[this.target]) {
            tasks.push('clean:' + this.target);
        }
        var config = grunt.config(this.target);

        // check if there is coffee:refresh config available
        if (config && config.refresh) {
            tasks.push(this.target + ':refresh');
        }
        // run the tasks
        grunt.task.run(tasks);

        // set the resetFlag back to true
        resetFlag = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue myself and I was able to come up with a solution for it inspired by the comments on this issue:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/14

It is actually for the grunt-contrib-watch plugin, but it should also work for grunt-regarde, as it has similar events.

The idea is to bind a callback the `watch` event, in which you add a new task to the grunt configuration with the changed file's path, then run it.

From my `Gruntfile.coffee`:

```
coffee:
    app:
        expand: true
        cwd: 'app/'
        src: ['*.coffee',"**/*.coffee"]
        dest: './public/temp'
        ext: '.js'
watch: 
    coffee:
        files: ['app/**/*.coffee']
        tasks: ['livereload']
        options:
            nospawn: true

grunt.event.on 'watch', (action, filepath) ->       
    cwd = 'app/'
    filepath = filepath.replace(cwd,'')
    grunt.config.set('coffee',
        changed:
            expand: true
            cwd: cwd
            src: filepath
            dest: './public/temp'
            ext: '.js'
    )
    grunt.task.run('coffee:changed')
```

The nospawn is important for the watch task, so it runs the new task before the livereload task. I am pretty sure regarde does not spawn child processes by default.

Answer (score 0):

`grunt.regarde.changed` is an array correct?

Should `src: ['<%= grunt.regarde.changed %>']`

be `src: '<%= grunt.regarde.changed %>'`

I looked through grunt-contrib-coffee's source for a second to see if it could be not correctly handling whatever you're giving it. Looked kind of likely that the stringified array you're giving it, doesn't get caught and dealt with.

I think what you're passing accidentally may be: `src: [ '[path1, path2, path3, etc]' ]`

If I'm way off base, leave a comment and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: `src: '<%= grunt.regarde.changed %>'` worked for me (needed to be wrapped in a string).