# Can grunt-regard be configured to run a subset of watch tasks instead of all tasks?

Tags: watch, gruntjs

I am using gruntjs to build my js application. My grunt file is setup to run two separate builds where 80% of the code is the same for both and depending on the build we include additional files and exclude some files.

I have grunt setup to run the two different builds correctly except I cant tell grunt-regard to run multiple times.

```
regarde:
  coffeeScripts:
    files: ['app/scripts/kiosk/*.coffee', 'app/scripts/*.coffee'],
    tasks: ['coffee:compileKiosk', 'livereload']
  stylusScripts:
    files: ['app/css/kiosk/*.styl', 'app/css/*.styl'],
    tasks: ['stylus:compileKiosk', 'livereload']
  coffeeScriptsWeb:
    files: ['app/scripts/web/*.coffee', app/scripts/*.coffee],
    tasks: ['coffee:compileWeb', 'livereload']
  stylusScriptsWeb:
    files: ['app/css/web/*.styl', 'app/css/*.styl],
    tasks: ['stylus:compileWeb', 'livereload']
```

I want to be able to do something similar to the tasks below, but only the first regarde task runs and the second is ignored.

```
grunt.registerTask 'watchKiosk', ['livereload-start', 'regarde:coffeeScripts', 'regarde:stylusScripts']
grunt.registerTask 'watchWeb', ['livereload-start', 'regarde:coffeeScriptsWeb', 'regarde:stylusScriptsWeb']
```

My folder structure looks like

```
app       (application root)
  scripts (contains common script files)
    kiosk (contains script files only for kiosk build)
    web   (contains script files only for web build)
  css     (contains common css files)
    kiosk (contains css files only for kiosk build)
    web   (contains css files only for web build)
```

Ideally when working with the web build I do not want to recompile all the kiosk files and web files when a file changes.

Is there any way to setup grunt to have multiple regarde tasks defined and run the specific task I want for the build I am working on?

If I run these grunt tasks the watch works but will rebuild files that are not part of the specific build I am working with

```
grunt.registerTask 'watchKiosk', ['livereload-start', 'regarde']
grunt.registerTask 'watchWeb', ['livereload-start', 'regarde']
```

Comment: I think you have to use grunt events. My answer here is not entirely the same use case as your, but it gives a general idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15496488/1916258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [asgoth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916258/asgoth) for his link, from the linked answer I was able to figure out a way to do this. This might not be the best way but it works.

I added two different configurations for my regarde task (one for the kiosk build and one for the web build) to the grunt file:

```
regardeKiosk:
  coffeeScripts:
    files: ['app/scripts/kiosk/*.coffee', 'app/scripts/*.coffee'],
    tasks: ['coffee:compileKiosk', 'livereload']
  stylusScripts:
    files: ['app/css/kiosk/*.styl', 'app/css/*.styl'],
    tasks: ['stylus:compileKiosk', 'livereload']
```

and

```
regardeWeb:
  coffeeScriptsWeb:
    files: ['app/scripts/web/*.coffee', app/scripts/*.coffee],
    tasks: ['coffee:compileWeb', 'livereload']
  stylusScriptsWeb:
    files: ['app/css/web/*.styl', 'app/css/*.styl],
    tasks: ['stylus:compileWeb', 'livereload']
```

Then I created a multi task that picks the correct configuration and updates the regarde config before starting the regard task.

```
#startWatch config
startWatch:
  web: 'Web'
  kiosk: 'Kiosk'

grunt.registerMultiTask 'startWatch', 'refreshing the changed file(s)', () ->
  #read regarde config and regarde template config. @data comes from startWatch config
  regardeConfig = grunt.config('regarde')
  correctConfig = grunt.config('regarde' + @data)

  #replace regarde config with the correct config
  grunt.config('regarde', correctConfig)

  #run regarde task
  grunt.task.run('regarde')
```

Then I am able to define my two grunt tasks and pick which regard task to run based on the build

```
grunt.registerTask 'watchKiosk', ['livereload-start', 'startWatch:kiosk']
grunt.registerTask 'watchWeb', ['livereload-start', 'startWatch:web']
```