# Grunt glob -- can we only copy only what is changed and keep the file structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-coffee

This question, I believe, can be applied to a variety of grunt tasks. I will use grunt-contrib-coffee in my example.

I have a dev directory with a complex file structure and a bunch of coffee files. When developing, I use this coffee task to copy all the files to a srv_dev directory.

```
coffee:
  srv_dev:
    files: [
      cwd: 'dev/'
      src: ['**/*.coffee', '!bower_components/**']
      dest: 'srv_dev/'
      expand: true
      ext: '.js'
    ]
    options:
      bare: true
      sourceMap: true
```

This keeps the structure intact and works okay, except that whenever I modify a file, it triggers a watch task which re-runs the coffee task. So every time I modify any one file, all of my coffee files are moved and re-compiled.

Is it possible to compile, and copy to a new directory, only the coffee files that are modified, while keeping the original directory structure?

Comment: [This might be what I'm looking for.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737638/1388017) Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076533/how-can-i-use-grunt-regarde-with-grunt-contrib-coffee-to-only-compile-changed-c?rq=1) and [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788731/grunt-watch-multiple-files-compile-only-changed?rq=1) Apparently I should've googled more.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722900/1388017), upvote @Norris.

It uses [grunt-newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer) and is easy as pie.